# Issues with installing GraphLab Create on Windows 7

Tags: python, python-2.7, graphlab

As part of my curricular, I was trying to install GraphLab Create following instructions given at https://dato.com/ site. My system is running on Windows 7 professional with 8 GB RAM and around 40 GB free hard disk space.

I did the following:

1. Installed [Windows 64-Bit Python 2.7 Graphical Installer](https://3230d63b5fc54e62148e-c95ac804525aac4b6dba79b00b39d1d3.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/Anaconda-2.3.0-Windows-x86_64.exe) as per the GraphLab Create instructions and then
2. Followed the steps in sequence under the section "Anaconda Python Install" as instructed in the [above](https://dato.com/) link.

My installation went successfully, but I am unable to use this package, import graphlab throwing error. The log file and the error is as below:

```
Added C:\Anaconda and C:\Anaconda\Scripts to PATH.

C:\Anaconda>conda create -n dato-env python=2.7
Fetching package metadata: ....
Solving package specifications: .
Package plan for installation in environment C:\Anaconda\envs\dato-env:

The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    setuptools-18.1            |           py27_0         646 KB
    wheel-0.24.0               |           py27_0         116 KB
    pip-7.1.2                  |           py27_0         1.4 MB
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:         2.2 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    pip:        7.1.2-py27_0
    python:     2.7.10-0
    setuptools: 18.1-py27_0
    wheel:      0.24.0-py27_0

Proceed ([y]/n)? Y

Fetching packages ...
setuptools-18. 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:01 624.09 kB/s
wheel-0.24.0-p 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   1.35 MB/s
pip-7.1.2-py27 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:02 737.94 kB/s
Extracting packages ...
[      COMPLETE      ]|##################################################| 100%
Linking packages ...
[      COMPLETE      ]|##################################################| 100%
#
# To activate this environment, use:
# > activate dato-env
#

C:\Anaconda>activate dato-env
Activating environment "dato-env"...

[dato-env] C:\Anaconda>conda update pip
Fetching package metadata: ....
# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at C:\Anaconda\envs\dato-env:
#
pip                       7.1.2                    py27_0

[dato-env] C:\Anaconda>conda install ipython-notebook
Fetching package metadata: ....
Solving package specifications: .
Package plan for installation in environment C:\Anaconda\envs\dato-env:

The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    decorator-4.0.2            |           py27_0          11 KB
    ipython_genutils-0.1.0     |           py27_0          32 KB
    mistune-0.7.1              |           py27_0         122 KB
    path.py-7.6                |           py27_0          41 KB
    pickleshare-0.5            |           py27_0           8 KB
    simplegeneric-0.8.1        |           py27_0           6 KB
    traitlets-4.0.0            |           py27_0          88 KB
    ipython-4.0.0              |           py27_0         969 KB
    jinja2-2.8                 |           py27_0         263 KB
    jupyter_core-4.0.4         |           py27_0          74 KB
    tornado-4.2.1              |           py27_0         510 KB
    jupyter_client-4.0.0       |           py27_0         129 KB
    nbformat-4.0.0             |           py27_0         155 KB
    ipykernel-4.0.3            |           py27_0         111 KB
    nbconvert-4.0.0            |           py27_0         306 KB
    notebook-4.0.4             |           py27_0         4.3 MB
    ipython-notebook-4.0.4     |           py27_0           5 KB
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:         7.0 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    certifi:            14.05.14-py27_0
    decorator:          4.0.2-py27_0
    ipykernel:          4.0.3-py27_0
    ipython:            4.0.0-py27_0
    ipython-notebook:   4.0.4-py27_0
    ipython_genutils:   0.1.0-py27_0
    jinja2:             2.8-py27_0
    jsonschema:         2.4.0-py27_0
    jupyter_client:     4.0.0-py27_0
    jupyter_core:       4.0.4-py27_0
    markupsafe:         0.23-py27_0
    mistune:            0.7.1-py27_0
    nbconvert:          4.0.0-py27_0
    nbformat:           4.0.0-py27_0
    notebook:           4.0.4-py27_0
    path.py:            7.6-py27_0
    pickleshare:        0.5-py27_0
    pygments:           2.0.2-py27_0
    pyreadline:         2.0-py27_0
    pyzmq:              14.7.0-py27_0
    simplegeneric:      0.8.1-py27_0
    ssl_match_hostname: 3.4.0.2-py27_0
    tornado:            4.2.1-py27_0
    traitlets:          4.0.0-py27_0

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Fetching packages ...
decorator-4.0. 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   3.74 MB/s
ipython_genuti 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   1.32 MB/s
mistune-0.7.1- 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   1.20 MB/s
path.py-7.6-py 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00 987.33 kB/s
pickleshare-0. 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   3.92 MB/s
simplegeneric- 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00 655.22 kB/s
traitlets-4.0. 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00 942.22 kB/s
ipython-4.0.0- 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:01 943.49 kB/s
jinja2-2.8-py2 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00 816.70 kB/s
jupyter_core-4 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00 901.24 kB/s
tornado-4.2.1- 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00 767.53 kB/s
jupyter_client 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00 409.79 kB/s
nbformat-4.0.0 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00 571.91 kB/s
ipykernel-4.0. 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   1.04 MB/s
nbconvert-4.0. 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00 454.87 kB/s
notebook-4.0.4 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:07 561.12 kB/s
ipython-notebo 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00 606.63 kB/s
Extracting packages ...
[      COMPLETE      ]|##################################################| 100%
Linking packages ...
[      COMPLETE      ]|##################################################| 100%

[dato-env] C:\Anaconda>pip install --upgrade --no-cache-dir https://get.dato.com
/GraphLab-Create/1.5.2/******@spsmail.cuny.edu/****-****-****-****-****
-****-****-****/GraphLab-Create-License.tar.gz
Collecting https://get.dato.com/GraphLab-Create/1.5.2/******@spsmail.cu
ny.edu/****-****-****-****-****-****-****-****/GraphLab-Create-License.tar.gz
  Downloading https://get.dato.com/GraphLab-Create/1.5.2/******@spsmail
.cuny.edu/****-****-****-****-****-****-****-****/GraphLab-Create-License.tar.gz

Collecting graphlab-create>=1.5.2 (from GraphLab-Create-License==1.5.2)
  Downloading GraphLab_Create-1.5.2-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl (41.4MB)
    100% |################################| 41.4MB 706kB/s
Collecting boto==2.33.0 (from graphlab-create>=1.5.2->GraphLab-Create-License==1
.5.2)
  Downloading boto-2.33.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.3MB)
    100% |################################| 1.3MB 611kB/s
Collecting prettytable==0.7.2 (from graphlab-create>=1.5.2->GraphLab-Create-Lice
nse==1.5.2)
  Downloading prettytable-0.7.2.tar.bz2
Collecting decorator==3.4.0 (from graphlab-create>=1.5.2->GraphLab-Create-Licens
e==1.5.2)
  Downloading decorator-3.4.0.tar.gz
Collecting librato-metrics==0.4.9 (from graphlab-create>=1.5.2->GraphLab-Create-
License==1.5.2)
  Downloading librato-metrics-0.4.9.tar.gz
Collecting multipledispatch>=0.4.7 (from graphlab-create>=1.5.2->GraphLab-Create
-License==1.5.2)
  Downloading multipledispatch-0.4.8.tar.gz
Collecting sseclient==0.0.8 (from graphlab-create>=1.5.2->GraphLab-Create-Licens
e==1.5.2)
  Downloading sseclient-0.0.8.tar.gz
Collecting requests==2.3.0 (from graphlab-create>=1.5.2->GraphLab-Create-License
==1.5.2)
  Downloading requests-2.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (452kB)
    100% |################################| 454kB 718kB/s
Collecting awscli==1.7.27 (from graphlab-create>=1.5.2->GraphLab-Create-License=
=1.5.2)
  Downloading awscli-1.7.27.tar.gz (336kB)
    100% |################################| 339kB 787kB/s
Collecting mixpanel-py==3.1.1 (from graphlab-create>=1.5.2->GraphLab-Create-Lice
nse==1.5.2)
  Downloading mixpanel-py-3.1.1.tar.gz
Collecting tornado==4.1 (from graphlab-create>=1.5.2->GraphLab-Create-License==1
.5.2)
  Downloading tornado-4.1.tar.gz (332kB)
    100% |################################| 335kB 602kB/s
Collecting six (from librato-metrics==0.4.9->graphlab-create>=1.5.2->GraphLab-Cr
eate-License==1.5.2)
  Downloading six-1.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting botocore<0.109.0,>=0.108.0 (from awscli==1.7.27->graphlab-create>=1.5
.2->GraphLab-Create-License==1.5.2)
  Downloading botocore-0.108.0.tar.gz (1.6MB)
    100% |################################| 1.6MB 413kB/s
Collecting bcdoc<0.15.0,>=0.14.0 (from awscli==1.7.27->graphlab-create>=1.5.2->G
raphLab-Create-License==1.5.2)
  Downloading bcdoc-0.14.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting colorama<=0.3.3,>=0.2.5 (from awscli==1.7.27->graphlab-create>=1.5.2-
>GraphLab-Create-License==1.5.2)
  Downloading colorama-0.3.3.tar.gz
Collecting docutils>=0.10 (from awscli==1.7.27->graphlab-create>=1.5.2->GraphLab
-Create-License==1.5.2)
  Downloading docutils-0.12.tar.gz (1.6MB)
    100% |################################| 1.6MB 481kB/s
Collecting rsa<=3.1.4,>=3.1.2 (from awscli==1.7.27->graphlab-create>=1.5.2->Grap
hLab-Create-License==1.5.2)
  Downloading rsa-3.1.4.tar.gz
Collecting certifi (from tornado==4.1->graphlab-create>=1.5.2->GraphLab-Create-L
icense==1.5.2)
  Downloading certifi-2015.04.28-py2.py3-none-any.whl (373kB)
    100% |################################| 376kB 553kB/s
Requirement already up-to-date: backports.ssl-match-hostname in c:\anaconda\envs
\dato-env\lib\site-packages (from tornado==4.1->graphlab-create>=1.5.2->GraphLab
-Create-License==1.5.2)
Collecting jmespath==0.7.1 (from botocore<0.109.0,>=0.108.0->awscli==1.7.27->gra
phlab-create>=1.5.2->GraphLab-Create-License==1.5.2)
  Downloading jmespath-0.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1 (from botocore<0.109.0,>=0.108.0->awscli=
=1.7.27->graphlab-create>=1.5.2->GraphLab-Create-License==1.5.2)
  Downloading python_dateutil-2.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (188kB)
    100% |################################| 192kB 356kB/s
Collecting pyasn1>=0.1.3 (from rsa<=3.1.4,>=3.1.2->awscli==1.7.27->graphlab-crea
te>=1.5.2->GraphLab-Create-License==1.5.2)
  Downloading pyasn1-0.1.8.tar.gz (75kB)
    100% |################################| 77kB 593kB/s
Installing collected packages: boto, prettytable, decorator, six, librato-metric
s, multipledispatch, requests, sseclient, jmespath, python-dateutil, botocore, d
ocutils, bcdoc, colorama, pyasn1, rsa, awscli, mixpanel-py, certifi, tornado, gr
aphlab-create, GraphLab-Create-License
  Running setup.py install for prettytable
  Found existing installation: decorator 4.0.2
    Uninstalling decorator-4.0.2:
      Successfully uninstalled decorator-4.0.2
  Running setup.py install for decorator
  Running setup.py install for librato-metrics
  Running setup.py install for multipledispatch
  Running setup.py install for sseclient
  Running setup.py install for botocore
  Running setup.py install for docutils
  Running setup.py install for colorama
  Running setup.py install for pyasn1
  Running setup.py install for rsa
  Running setup.py install for awscli
  Running setup.py install for mixpanel-py
  Found existing installation: certifi 14.5.14
    DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (certifi) has been d
eprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that
uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
    Uninstalling certifi-14.5.14:
      Successfully uninstalled certifi-14.5.14
  Found existing installation: tornado 4.2.1
    DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (tornado) has been d
eprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that
uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
    Uninstalling tornado-4.2.1:
      Successfully uninstalled tornado-4.2.1
  Running setup.py install for tornado
  Running setup.py install for GraphLab-Create-License
Successfully installed GraphLab-Create-License-1.5.2 awscli-1.7.27 bcdoc-0.14.0
boto-2.33.0 botocore-0.108.0 certifi-2015.4.28 colorama-0.3.3 decorator-3.4.0 do
cutils-0.12 graphlab-create-1.5.2 jmespath-0.7.1 librato-metrics-0.4.9 mixpanel-
py-3.1.1 multipledispatch-0.4.8 prettytable-0.7.2 pyasn1-0.1.8 python-dateutil-2
.4.2 requests-2.3.0 rsa-3.1.4 six-1.9.0 sseclient-0.0.8 tornado-4.1

[dato-env] C:\Anaconda>python
Python 2.7.10 |Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit)| (default, May 28 2015, 16:44:52) [MSC v.
1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://binstar.org
>>> import graphlab
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named graphlab
>>>
```

While I can see the folder C:\Anaconda\envs\dato-env on my system, import graphlab is throwing errors.

Appreciate help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been able to resolve the issue and thought of post the same if it helps others. Actually it is the window's environment which dato's activate script (C:\Anaconda\Scripts\activate.bat where C is/was my <drive letter>) has messed up. Add

```
set PREACTIVATE_PATH=C:\Anaconda;C:\Anaconda\Scripts;
call set PATH=%%PATH:%PREACTIVATE_PATH%=%%
```

just above "set CONDA_NEW_ENV=%~1" line and

```
cd %ANACONDA_ENVS%\%CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV%
```

just after "set PROMPT=[%CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV%] %PROMPT%" line will fix the issue. Also note that you cannot use the standard shortcuts created under your Start menu as you need to activate the new environment at every time.

So the startup process will be:

1. Click on "Anaconda Command Prompt" under "Anaconda (***)" at Startup
2. Type "activate <your environment name> and press enter
3. Start ipython or python notebook from this shell

That's it, it was that easy, but took my several hours to figure it out.

Comment: Hi, I honestly don't understand how you resolved the situation as I have something similar here. "set PREACTIVATE_PATH=C:\Anaconda;C:\Anaconda\Scripts;
call set PATH=%%PATH:%PREACTIVATE_PATH%=%%
just above "set CONDA_NEW_ENV=%~1" line and..."  I find this a bit confusing. Please can you explain by rephrasing? Thanks.